# Programming an Interactive Server Console on Windows

Tags: c, windows, console-application

I'm writing a game with multiplayer functionality, and I need to write a server console. A simple "read from stdin -> process input -> write output" loop won't work because the server has to be running and may print log messages while the server admin is typing in the server console. I've seen the tecla and Editline libraries for UNIX/Linux systems, but haven't found anything for Windows. What are some good libraries for that sort of thing?

In case you didn't understand, this is pretty much the same as [Interactive console programming for c/c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537288/interactive-console-programming-for-c-c) but for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general approaches to this problem:

1. Run your entire server in one thread, and control the thread with a main loop that uses asynchronous IO to determine where events (incoming packets, console keypresses etc) are coming from and handle them.

   In unix systems you have the `select()` call and some more advanced variants like `poll()` and epoll()` in some later unix/linux versions. In windows they call it [Overlapped IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686358%28VS.85%29.aspx).
2. Have separate threads manage separate parts of the server.  The usual approach is, one thread for each client, plus on thread for a console.  Here instead of trying to write a main loop you have to make judicious use of [mutexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [condition variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and such to make sure that threads don't step on each other's toes.